# Storage in PhoneGap

Tags: database, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I trying to use PhoneGap for developing a simple app that has some kind of DB with a couple of values and the data is retrieved from there and showed. The thing is, I a newbie in this. I know there is a plugin named storage but i just can't find anything that enlight me enough for doing this. Can anyone help me or tell me where can I get a good tutorial for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to tell you about two storage mechanisms. First one is a SQL database. Second one is localStorage.

SQL organises your data in a good way, local storage may be your "cache", some kind of qiuck access memory. Both are very usefull. Both work on multiple platforms.

Here are some examples showing storing and accessing data in local storage:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("key", "value");  
var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key");
```

I think you will easily find how to access database.
I am sure you will find this interesting:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Comment: I would be greateful if you accepted my answer. Of course if you find it worth it:)

Comment: I've accepted it now. I was taking a look. It worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can find [Phonegap Development](http://www.techooks.com/html5-storage-in-mobile-applications-phonegap-storage-api/) storage API.

It's very useful for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

If your values are small and simple, then you can simply use the `window.localstorage`. 
**In your javascript**:
To create or update:
`window.localStorage.setItem(name,value)`
To delete:
`window.localStorage.removeItem(name)`
To get:
`window.localStorage.getItem(name)`

Comment: You dont need the window. syntax within Phonegap / Cordova - just using localStorage will work.

Comment: @Drew Dahlman - I'm sorry, can you tell me how to use this localStorage? It's just like the example Kiran gave, without the "window."? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah just like Kiran said - he was correct just leave out the window - I have noticed that the window syntax doesn't work properly within phonegap. So if you want to save an item localStorage.setItem('name','foo') if you then wrote localStorage.getItem('name') it would return "foo".

Comment: Drew, I have been using window.localStorage all the time and didn't have any issue. Any idea what might I be missing? Even phonegap docs refer to window.localStorage: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage